# How I can increase the font size of the watches in debug mode in codeblocks?

Tags: debugging, codeblocks, watch

CodeBlocks watch font size is so small by default.I want to increase it for a better view.
How i can do that ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not change the *watches window* text font.

But you can change the font and its size for the *watch under (mouse) cursor*.

Go to *Menu* -> *Settings* -> *Debugger*

Find "Value Tooltip Font" while "Common" option (at left, up) is active.

Press "Choose" and the select your desired font.